# using ajax for acts_as_votable to avoid page reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm using acts_as_voteable for upvote/downvote on a tweets page which works fine. however it reloads the page when i do this which i want to avoid

```html
<% @tweets.each do |tweet|  %>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-description">
      <h4><%= link_to tweet.user.username, user_path(tweet.user) %></h4>
      <p class="tweet-content"><%= tweet.content %></p>
      <p><%= tweet.created_at.strftime("%B %d %Y, %l:%M%P") %></p>
      <%= link_to like_tweet_path(tweet), method: :put do %>
      <p>Upvote <%= tweet.get_upvotes.size %>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to dislike_tweet_path(tweet), method: :put do %>
      Downvote <%= tweet.get_downvotes.size %></p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

```html
class TweetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index]

   def index
    # @tweets = Tweet.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @tweets = Tweet.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 7).order('created_at DESC')

    @tweet = Tweet.new
    @user = current_user
  end

  def show
    @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    # @tweet = Tweet.new
  end

  def create
    # @user = current_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @tweet = Tweet.new(tweet_params)
    @tweet.user = @user
    if @tweet.save
    redirect_to user_tweets_path
  end
  end

  def edit
    @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
    @tweet.update(tweet_params)
    redirect_to tweets_path
  end

  def upvote
  @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
  @tweet.upvote_by current_user
  # redirect_to :tweets
   if request.xhr?
    head :ok
  else
    redirect_to tweets_path
  end
end

def downvote
  @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
  @tweet.downvote_by current_user
  redirect_to :tweets
end

  private
  def tweet_params
    params.require(:tweet).permit(:content)
  end
end
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `remote: true` in the `link_to` tag.

For example:

You have `<%= link_to like_tweet_path(tweet), method: :put do %>`

You can have it this way `<%= link_to like_tweet_path(tweet), method: :put, remote: true do %>`

Then just handle the request with `format.js`

Comment: the format.js is the part that im having the issue with unfortunatly aha

Comment: Gotcha! Well, can you clarify, what's the part of the `format.js` you are having an issue with?